# I want to set dynamic max file upload in dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

HTML

```
<script src="./assets/js/dropzone.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="maxFileUpload" value="5"/>
```

dropzone.js

```
(function() {
.
.
Dropzone.prototype.defaultOptions = {
      maxFiles: $("#maxFileUpload").val(),
```

can't get value. But value the undefined.
I try document.getElementById('maxFileUpload').value
It doesn't work.

Do not know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

try updating the dz object on change (assuming the user can change)

```
(function() {

    var dz = new Dropzone({
        //init
    });

    $("#maxFileUpload").change(function(){
        dz.options.maxFiles = parseInt($(this).val());
    })

});
```